# Program "clean" shutdown results in an error code from the system

Tags: c++

I'm creating a program that runs a couple of scripts and has multiple threads / datastructure uses. When I shutdown the program, it quits normally but there is an error code received when I check $LastExitCode.

[image]

What can I do to make sure that the program exits correctly causing the exit code to be shown as 0?

Comment: You've got an access violation. Please show a [mre] and don't post images of text

Comment: Convert that number to hex and search for that. Sadly I can't copy text from an image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=1073741819 works, too.